# Trying to Install Ubuntu 14.10 but will not boot from the hard drive

Tags: boot, grub2, hard-drive

Okay, I've been at this for 3 days now. I am installing Ubuntu Via USB and I'm using the Universal USB installer and downloaded the Ubuntu 14.10 version. I tried two ways to install it to the hard disk. First, I tried the "try Ubuntu without installing" and once I got to the desktop I hit the icon to install to hard drive. After all the settings and installing it asked to restart. I popped out the USB and it doesn't boot from the hard drive at all. I also tried selecting, "Install Ubuntu" from the menu and still nothing. Whether if I leave my USB in or out nothing happens.

I read forums but still nothing. I'm not dual booting, All I have is a Lenovo V570 with a Seagate 750 GB Hard drive. It's been completely wiped with no OS on it. So it's fresh and brand new. I've tried the previous version of Ubuntu (14.04) as well. I'm confused and need help trying to figure this out. I do not have access to a disk and prefer to try to do this through a USB. I do have disks but for some reason it won't recognize it. Anyway, can someone help?

Comment: Did you define a Persistent Area on your stick? Simply take LILI (http://www.linuxliveusb.com/) to setup your stick and define a persistent area with about 500 MB, than it should works.

Comment: If you successfully installed but can't boot, my first suggestion it to try boot-repair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Okay, Sorry I'm in the military and been in the field for the last couple of days. I tried both methods right before I left. I tried the boot - repair but it wouldn't let me partition it correctly and kept saying an error. I forgot. Soon as I try this again I will post to let you know. But, for addicted. Im not trying to boot from my usb. Im trying to install ubuntu to a brand new harddrive.

Comment: Brandon, in the [official Installation instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop) at step 4, take "something else" and set the "device for boot loader installation" to `/dev/sda`

Comment: Any feed-back on the last comment above?

Comment: Sorry Just now seeing this. Let me try that.

Comment: Okay I just tried the something else option and I created a new partition and I made 1 primary ext4 /, EFi Boot, and a swap. But yet still no installation.

Comment: I even tried throwing it into a VM. However, my laptop doesn't support VT. Can I catch a break?

Comment: Okay, UPDATE!!!!!!!!!! I finally got it! However, I'm dual booting with Windows 8.1 

So when I installed Windows 8.1 on it i made the partition smaller. I installed ubuntu with the following XX GB I left for ubuntu itself.

I selected the Free Space which was like 122500 or something like that.

Made a Primary partition using EXT4 and "/" and a swap area doubling my 6gbs of RAM for the swap area.

Now, after i installed it and the computer restarted I noticed It was only booting into Ubuntu. From there I installed boot-repair and re-installed the GRUB and from there it works perfectly fine!!!